# BLUE J Java Methode calls a Methode

Tags: java, bluej

Okay guys, I can construct a `Person`, I can call the `setBirthday` method, and the window appears to give the parameters to the method, but as soon as I call the `checkBirthday` method with a false date, it just prints the statement and no new window opens for the `setBrithday` method. How do I manage to open a new window to give the parameters to `setBrithday` in the `checkBirthday` method? I'm using BlueJ.

```
public Person(short day, short month, short year)
{
    this.day = day;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
    this.birthday = day+"."+month+"."+year;
}


public void setBirthday(short day, short month, short year)
{
    this.day = day;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;
    this.birthday = day+"."+month+"."+year;
}


public void checkBirthday()
{
    if(day > 30 && (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11))
    {
        System.out.println("The entered birthday is invalid. Please re-enter your birthday.");
        setBirthday(day, month, year);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow parameters to be passed in to `checkBirthday`

Try:

```
public void checkBirthday(short day, short month, short year)
```

Over:

```
public void checkBirthday()
```

I'm really confused as to this to why you'd want to do this, you'd probably want to call `checkBirthday` inside of `setBirthday`.